# What does the .0 in shared library names refer to?

Tags: shared-libraries

When trying to start third-party binaries under linux, I very often get an error along the lines of "libX.so.0" was not found, even though libX.so is located in my /usr/lib. I always thought just soft-linking /usr/lib/libX.so to /usr/lib/libX.so.0 would work, but I seem to have been wrong.

```
/usr/lib/libpng12.so.0: version `PNG12_0' not found
```

Is the _0 in this name related to the .0 in libpng12.so.0? If so, what exactly does it mean? Is there some way to identify the source code version I need to download from either the `PNG12_0` identifier, or the libpng12.so.0 name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I very often get an error along the lines of "libX.so.0" was not found, even though libX.so is located in my /usr/lib

You can read about external library versioning [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-0690/chapter5-5.html).

> Is the _0 in this name related to the .0 in libpng12.so.0?

Very likely yes.

> If so, what exactly does it mean?

The *symbol* versioning is a GNU extension to library versioning. I can't find a good description of it, but it allows a *single* externally-versioned library (e.g. `libc.so.6`) to provide multiple incompatible implementations of the same symbol (before symbol versioning, you had to update the external version of the library every time you introduced incompatible interface; but with symbol versioning you don't).

Long story short: the `_0` means whatever developers decided it means.